# Limiting character in textbox input

Tags: javascript, html

please be nice. I'm trying to create a page which sets limit and cut the excess (from the specified limit). Example: Limit is 3. then, I'll input abc if I input d it must say that its limit is reached and the abc will remain. My problem is that it just delete my previous input and make new inputs. Hoping for your great cooperation. Thanks.

```
    <html>
    <script type="text/javascript">

     function disable_btn_limit(btn_name)
     {
     /* this function is used to disable and enable buttons and textbox*/
    if(btn_name == "btn_limit")
{
        document.getElementById("btn_limit").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("ctr_limit_txt").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("btn_edit_limit").disabled = false;
}
         if(btn_name == "btn_edit_limit")
{
        document.getElementById("btn_limit").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("ctr_limit_txt").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("btn_edit_limit").disabled = true;
}
   }

     function check_content(txtarea_content)
    {
        /*This function is used to check the content*/
    // initialize an array
var txtArr = new Array();
       //array assignment
      //.split(delimiter) function of JS is used to separate 
     //values according to groups; delimiter can be ;,| and etc
txtArr = txtarea_content.split("");
var newcontent = "";
var momo =  new Array();
var trimmedcontent = "";
var re = 0;
var etoits;
var etoits2;

    //for..in is a looping statement for Arrays in JS. This is similar to foreach in C# 
    //Syntax: for(index in arr_containter) {}
for(ind_val in txtArr)
{
    var bool_check = check_if_Number(txtArr[ind_val])
    if(bool_check == true)
    {
        //DO NOTHING
    }
    else
    {


        //trim_content(newcontent); 
        newcontent += txtArr[ind_val];
        momo[ind_val] = txtArr[ind_val];
    }
}
var isapa = new Array();
var s;
re = trim_content(newcontent);  

for(var x = 0; x < re - 1; x++){

    document.getElementById("txtarea_content").value += momo[x];
    document.getElementById("txtarea_content").value = "";

}

     }
       function trim_content(ContentVal)
     {
//This function is used to determine length of content
//parseInt(value) is used to change String values to Integer data types.
//Please note that all value coming from diplay are all in String data Type
var limit_char =parseInt(document.getElementById("ctr_limit_txt").value);
var eto;
if(ContentVal.length > (limit_char-1))
{ 
    alert("Length is greater than the value specified above: " +limit_char);
    eto = limit_char ;
    etoits = document.getElementById("txtarea_content").value;
    //document.getElementById("txtarea_content").value = "etoits";
    return eto;
    //for(var me = 0; me < limit_char; me++)
    //{document.getElementById("txtarea_content").value = "";}
}
return 0;
  }

    function check_if_Number(ContentVal)
{
   //This function is used to check if a value is a number or not
   //isNaN, case sensitive, JS function used to determine if the values are 
        //numbers or not. TRUE = not a number, FALSE = number
if(isNaN(ContentVal))
{
    return false;
}
else
{ alert("Input characters only!");
    return true;
}
      }



</script>
   <table>
   <tr>
   <td>
  <input type="text" name="ctr_limit_txt" id="ctr_limit_txt"/>
   </td>
        <td>
        <input type="button" name="btn_limit" id="btn_limit" value="Set Limit"         onClick="javascript:disable_btn_limit('btn_limit');"/>
     </td>
     <td>
  <input type="button" name="btn_edit_limit" id="btn_edit_limit" value="Edit Limit"       disabled="true" onClick="javascript:disable_btn_limit('btn_edit_limit');"/>
     </td>
   </tr>
        <tr>
   <td colspan="2">
  <textarea name="txtarea_content" id="txtarea_content" onKeyPress="javascript:check_content(this.value);"></textarea>
     <br>
    *Please note that you cannot include <br>numbers inside the text area
     </td>
 </tr>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing with this:

```
for(var x = 0; x < re - 6; x++){
    document.getElementById("txtarea_content").value += momo[x];
    document.getElementById("txtarea_content").value = "";
}
```

Comment: it works but the new input must be cut. for example 3 is the limit, "abc" if I press d, the output is "abcd" which should be "abc" only @avexdesigns

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If the condition is satisfied return true, otherwise return false.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function check_content(){
            var text = document.getElementById("txtarea_content").value;
            if(text.length >= 3){
                alert('Length should not be greater than 3');
                return false;
            } else { 
            return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <textarea name="txtarea_content" id="txtarea_content" onkeypress=" return check_content();"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works. I have simulated in jsfiddle, have a look in it http://jsfiddle.net/sbp96/

Comment: cool! It worked but the user should be the one will be specifying the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the extra character from the text area, you can prevent the character from being written in the first place

```
function check_content(event) {  //PARAMETER is the event NOT the content
    txtarea_content = document.getElementById("txtarea_content").value; //Get the content 

    [...]

    re = trim_content(newcontent);

    if (re > 0) {
        event.preventDefault();   // in case the content exceeds the limit, prevent defaultaction ie write the extra character
    }

    /*for (var x = 0; x < re - 1; x++) {
    document.getElementById("txtarea_content").value += momo[x];
    document.getElementById("txtarea_content").value = "";
    }*/
}
```

And in the HTML (parameter is the event):

```
<textarea ... onKeyPress="javascript:check_content(event);"></textarea>
```

Comment: I tested it and it worked. You need to put the prevent default in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why the maxlength attribute on a text input wouldn't work for so few characters? In your case, you would have:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="3" />
```

or if HTML5, you could still use a textarea:

```
<textarea maxlength="3"> ...
```

And then just have a label that indicates a three-character limit on any input.

Comment: nope, the limit must be set by the user and any excess input must be cut.